# attribute binding in angular 2 issue with svg

Tags: angular, svg

I have issue with attribute binding

```
@Component({
    selector: '[app-shape]',
    template: `
    <svg:image [attr.x]="helpline_x" [attr.y]="helpline_y" width="460" height="460" id="helpline" style="display:none" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink"
                                [attr.xlink:href]="helpline_href"></svg:image>

    `,
})

export class ShapeComponent {

    helpline_href = "Line.png";
    helpline_x = 0; helpline_y = 0;

    setupShape(): void {
        this.helpline_href = "1";
    }
}
```

When i call setupShape() from another component after include this Component: `ShapeComponent.setupShape();`
The xlink:href do not change.

But when i add more code, xlink:href will change to "1".

```
setupShape(): void {
      this.applyToDesigner();
      this.helpline_href = "1";
}
applyToDesigner():void {
setTimeout(function() {
      this.helpline.setAttribute("xlink:href","2");
   }, 100); 
}
```

Who can explore with you about it?

Comment: You are saying that you call a method from another component yet you don't include the code in how you do so.

Comment: what is `this.helpline`??

Comment: `setTimeout(function() {` replace it by `setTimeout(() => {`

Comment: also `setupShape(): void {
      applyToDesigner();
      }` to `setupShape(): void {
      this.applyToDesigner();
      
}`

Comment: @micronyks Yes, i use this.applyToDesigner(); Thanks for the advice. But it do not that i need.

Comment: @PankajParkar That is id of element above, but I don't know why is it.

Comment: @PankajParkar when use `setTimeout(()=> {}`. It is not exist. Perhaps it happens when `setTimeout(function() {`

Comment: If you want to access `this` in a callback, you need to use arrow functions or `.bind(this)` otherwise `this` will point to the caller instead of to the component class.

Comment: @GünterZöchbauer Yes, i see, thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've resolved this issue. Cause i was use

```
    import { ShapeComponent } from './shape/shape.component';
    @Component({
      selector: 'my-app',
      templateUrl: "app.component.html",
       providers: [
         ShapeComponent
       ],
    })
    constructor(private shapeComponent: ShapeComponent) {  }
    ... 
    //call this
    this.shapeComponent.setupShape();
```

Instead i should use ViewChild and Delete providers:

```
import { ShapeComponent } from './shape/shape.component';
        @Component({
          selector: 'my-app',
          templateUrl: "app.component.html"
        })
        @ViewChild(ShapeComponent) shapeComponent: ShapeComponent;
        ... 
        //call this
        this.shapeComponent.setupShape();
```

Now, I can change xlink:href to "1" without `applyToDesigner()`

Result: Cause by I have confusion between ViewChild and Service Providers.

End up: Don't use provider for component.